# Which addresses to use when filling out form I-130

Tags: usa, greencard

I'm preparing the [form I-130](http://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/files/form/i-130.pdf) to start the process of gaining US residency for my foreign-born wife.

Lines B2 and C2 ask for my address and hers, respectively.  Later, on lines C18 and C19 I'm also asked for my spouse's current and future addresses.

The unofficial, line-by-line instructions [here](http://www.immihelp.com/forms/i-130-petition-for-alien-relative.html) say:

> #### Part B
>
> **2-5.**
> Self-explanatory
>
> **18.**
> Your US address should preferably be the same as your relative's address, otherwise USCIS may get suspicious.
>
> While, it is possible that you may want to spend some time away from your relative for school or work reason, it is best to put your permanent address in US same as your relative's US address.
>
> If you have a compelling reason to put different address, attach detailed explanation with the application or consult an immigration attorney.

My situation is that I will be staying outside of the US with my wife until the application process is completed.  I also prefer to receive my US mail to a commercial mailbox/scanning service, rather than to the physical address where we'll be staying.  So which address(es) should I use?

My best guess at this point:

- B2 (my address): Enter the address of my commercial mailbox
- C2 (relative's address): Enter her current foreign address
- C18: Enter the physical address where we intend to live in the US
- C19: Enter her current foreign address again
- Attach a letter explaining the situation

Is this the best course of action?

Alternately I could list my foreign address on B2, along with hers. But I feel that mail to the US address will be more reliable, faster, and cheaper.

Comment: On ours I consistently put my foreign address, for both USCIS and NVC. I was pleasantly surprised when the majority of the mail arrived, but not all of it did, and at one point that slowed down our process. You don't need to receive most of the mail they send you, if you're willing to call (and wait on hold) to find out where you are in the process. Most (but it seemed not all?) of their notifications will be sent by email, too. Don't forget the G-1145!

Comment: @DanGetz: Thanks for the G-1145 tip. I didn't know that existed.